# Find a subset of $S = \{(1, 0, i), (i, 2, -3), (2-i, 1+i, i)\}$ that forms a basis for $\textsf V = \operatorname{span}(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^3$ and the subset
$$S = \{(1, 0, i), (i, 2, -3), (2-i, 1+i, i)\}$$

Let $\textsf V$ denote $\operatorname{span}(S)$. Find a subset of $S$ that forms a basis for $\textsf V$.

How do I find the subset for something? I can put the vectors into matrix form and make them equal to $x, y, z$ respectfully but from there, I don't know how to proceed.

Am I missing a definition and and a series of steps? I know that a basis in simple terms is :

> The minimal amount of vectors that are linearly independent and spans
>    $\textsf V$.

Comment: $S$ should be a subset of $V$ consisting of $3$ vectors.  Do you know how to tell if the $3$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know the linear dependence between those vectors? Well, I'll use the definition, suppose there exists complex scalars $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} = a_1\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\i \end{pmatrix}+a_2\begin{pmatrix} 2-i\\1+i\\i \end{pmatrix}+a_3\begin{pmatrix} i\\2\\-3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2-i&i\\0&1+i&2\\i&i&-3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_3 \end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$
then, finding the row reduced echelon form of this matrix, yields that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-1+4i\\0&1&1-i\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then, the system has infinite solutions, so $ S $ cannot be linearly independent. We quickly see that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1-4i\\-1+i\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a solution of that system. But also, is a solution of the original system, $(1)$, that is :
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} = (1-4i)\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\i \end{pmatrix}+(-1+i)\begin{pmatrix} 2-i\\1+i\\i \end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix} i\\2\\-3 \end{pmatrix}$$
or
$$(i,2,-3)=(-1+4i)(1,0,i)+(1-i)(2-i,1+i,i)$$
Thus, a basis for $\textsf V$ consist of
$$S\setminus \{ (i,2,-3) \} = \{ (1,0,i),(2-i,1+i,i) \}$$

Comment: Does it need to be mentioned that the two remaining vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: It is a question?

Comment: Yes; to be pedantic it should be mentioned, but maybe it is so apparent that it goes without saying

Comment: It is clear, since one is not a scalar multiple of the other. That's right.

Comment: I agree; it was merely a comment

Comment: Sure, thanks! :)

Comment: @Azif00 what does the '\' mean? To formally write it do I just go: $\{(,2,−3)\}=\{(1,0,),(2−,1+,)\}$

Comment: Is the "difference" between sets : $A \setminus B$ is the set of all the elements that are members of $A$ but not members of $B$. In this case, means that you take the element $(i,2,-3)$ from $S$. I don't know exactly what you mean by writing that formally, but that is clearly false.

Answer (score 1):

The span of $S$ is $2$-dimensional because $(i,2,-3)-(1-i)(2-i,1+i,i)-(4i-1)(1,0,i)=0.$

Comment: Another way to show that the vectors in $S$ are not linearly independent would be to show that the determinant of the "vectors in matrix form" is $0$